# How to compile C++ with CMake and -L/usr/include/mariadb/mysql -lmariadbclient

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, mariadb

My C++ file includes the mariadb/mysql.h as following.

```
#include <mariadb/mysql.h>
```

I compile my C++ file as following.

```
g++ -std=c++2a -g main.cpp -o main -lmariadbclient
```

It works fine. But if I want to compile my C++ file using CMakeLists.txt. How to compile the C++ source code with `-lmariadbclient` using CMake?

Comment: `-L/usr/include/mariadb/mysql` seems like the wrong location for a library. This should be the include folder not the location of the compiled library.

Comment: For CMake I searched and found a finder module here: [https://github.com/viaduck/cmake-modules/blob/master/FindMariaDBClient.cmake](https://github.com/viaduck/cmake-modules/blob/master/FindMariaDBClient.cmake) you would find_package(MariaDBClient REQUIRED) and target_link_libraries(mytargetname MariaDBClient::MariaDBClient) after you add the finder module to a folder CMake searched.

Comment: This line shows you how to add an additional search path for finder modules: [https://github.com/viaduck/openssl-cmake/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L37](https://github.com/viaduck/openssl-cmake/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L37) it means in your project directory you would have a cmake folder with that finder module from the previous comment. You would use this list(APPEND ...) before you find_package()

Comment: @drescherjm I don't know what it does actually, but it could compile the code and it works.

Comment: I did not answer this as a formal answer because I can't really test this easily. I mean I would have to install mariadb and create a project ...

Comment: If your comment was about `-L/usr/include/mariadb/mysql`  you can remove this part from the command line and it still should do the same thing. `-L` means add an additional library folder where the compiled library exists to tell the linker where to look if the location is not a system default location. A `/usr/include` is not the correct place for such a file. You should not have any .a or .so files in that folder at all.

Comment: You are right! I have removed -L/usr/include/mariadb/mysql and it still works. How to compile the source code with `-lmariadbclient` using CMake ?

Comment: Read my other comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like major distros ship with a pkg-config file for mariadb called "mysqlclient.pc".

So you can do:

```
find_package(FindPkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(mariadb REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET "mysqlclient")
```

and then link it to your program like so:

```
target_link_libraries(my_program PUBLIC PkgConfig::mariadb)
```

Comment: What does PUBLIC mean?

Comment: Should anything link to `my_program` then the mariadb dependency is propagated. Largely irrelevant for an executable, can be `PRIVATE` too if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in the main CMakeLists.txt.

```
list(INSERT CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 0 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules")

find_package(MariaDBClient REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(
    your_project_name
    MariaDBClient::MariaDBClient
)
```

In the same directory as the main `CMakeLists.txt`, create the directory `cmake-modules` and create the file `FindMariaDBClient.cmake` in the `cmake-modules` directory.

Add the following in the `FindMariaDBClient.cmake` file.

```
find_path(MariaDBClient_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES mysql.h PATH_SUFFIXES mariadb mysql)

set(BAK_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
find_library(MariaDBClient_LIBRARY
    NAMES mariadb libmariadb mariadbclient libmariadbclient mysqlclient 
    libmysqlclient
    PATH_SUFFIXES mariadb mysql
)
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${BAK_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(MariaDBClient DEFAULT_MSG 
MariaDBClient_LIBRARY MariaDBClient_INCLUDE_DIR)

if(MariaDBClient_FOUND)
    if(NOT TARGET MariaDBClient::MariaDBClient)
        add_library(MariaDBClient::MariaDBClient UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
        set_target_properties(MariaDBClient::MariaDBClient PROPERTIES
            INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${MariaDBClient_INCLUDE_DIR}"
            IMPORTED_LOCATION "${MariaDBClient_LIBRARY}")
    endif()
endif()

mark_as_advanced(MariaDBClient_INCLUDE_DIR MariaDBClient_LIBRARY)

set(MariaDBClient_LIBRARIES ${MariaDBClient_LIBRARY})
set(MariaDBClient_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MariaDBClient_INCLUDE_DIR})
```